# bash/sed/awk: replace arbitrary substring in arbitrary files

Tags: bash, sed, substitution

**Update:**

I have tried markp-fuso's answer and it worked like a charm

I'm starting to get frustrated here as I'm not a daily user of bash/sed and the like.

**Starting point:**

I have many subfolders with many source files (`.c,.cpp,.cxx`).
These source files are referenced for compilation in project files (`.vcxproj`).

**What I want to do:**

I want to find all source files that contain the string `#import`. I then want to find all project files that reference those source files.
I then want to edit all occurences of these references inplace within these project files
e.g. `<Include="folder/file.cpp"/>` -> `<Include="folder/file.cpp" Attribute="Value"/>`

**What I have tried:**

```
egrep -lir --include=*.{c,cpp,cxx} "(#import)" ./e3 | xargs -L 1 basename | egrep -ir --include=*.vcxproj -f - ./e3 | sed 's/:/ /g'
```

which produces a list like that:

```
./src/base/base.vcxproj     <ClCompile Include="Folder1\Folder1File1.cpp" />
./src/mod/mod.vcxproj     <ClCompile Include="Folder2\Folder2File1.cpp" />
./src/ext/ext.vcxproj     <ClCompile Include="Folder3\Folder3File1.cpp" />
```

So I then tried

```
egrep -lir --include=*.{c,cpp,cxx} "(#import)" ./e3 | xargs -L 1 basename | egrep -ir --include=*.vcxproj -f - ./e3 | sed 's/:/ /g' | awk '{ sed -iE 's/($2,$3)/\1 Attribute="Value"/g' }'
```

which errors out with

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I have tried a solution with a shell script, which didn't work either and I don't know if and how to solve above error message. I'm open to any solution as long as it's running within bash, can even be more gross than what I came up with.

Comment: `awk '{ sed -iE ... }'` -- ...err, what? `awk` requires awk source code. `sed` is not a valid statement or function in the awk language.

Comment: To be clear, awk and sed are not well-chosen tools for this job. Better to use XML-aware tools (XMLStarlet, etc), or a language that incorporates a XML library (Python has lots of standard-library options, ElementTree being the best).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy My bad, I thought awk would error out on an unrecognized command. Unfortunately it has to be done in bash or a shell script

Comment: ...well, you're getting a bash error instead of an awk error because you have a single quote inside your single-quoted string, so it doesn't all get parsed by awk and goes back into a context where bash is looking at it.

Comment: ...that said, "bash or shell script" is ambiguous. I mean, _awk_ is a separate programming language from bash, just as Python is. You can put Python inside a bash script almost as easily as you can put awk inside a bash script. If awk is okay, then you surely aren't asking for a 100% pure-bash solution.

Comment: You really don't want to replace text "in place".  Disk is cheap.  Write a new directory tree with the changes you want.  Attempting to change files "in place" is a recipe for data corruption.  Note that I write "in place" in quotes because tools like `gnu-sed` with their misnamed in-place option do not edit files in place; they create new files.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Corrupted data won't be an issue in my case. Changes will be discarded after compile, worst case: compile breaks. Thanks for the insight, though. Will try your suggestion for the sake of learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup:

```
mkdir -p src/{base,mod,ext}

echo 'some stuff on this line
             <ClCompile Include="Folder1\Folder1File1.cpp" />
some more stuff on this line' > src/base/base.vcxproj

echo 'some stuff on this line
          <ClCompile Include="Folder2\Folder2File1.cpp" />
some more stuff on this line' > src/mod/mod.vcxproj

echo 'some stuff on this line
           <ClCompile Include="Folder3\Folder3File1.cpp" />
some more stuff on this line' > src/ext/ext.vcxproj
```

For the sake of getting something working in my environment I've placed the intermediate data in a local file:

```
$ cat proj.dat
./src/base/base.vcxproj    <ClCompile Include="Folder1\Folder1File1.cpp" />
./src/mod/mod.vcxproj    <ClCompile Include="Folder2\Folder2File1.cpp" />
./src/ext/ext.vcxproj    <ClCompile Include="Folder3\Folder3File1.cpp" />
```

One idea using parameter substitution:

```
while read -r fname oldstring                                # 2nd-Nth space-delimited fields go into the single variable "oldstring"
do
    oldstring="${oldstring//\\/\\\\}"                        # escape literal backslashes
    newstring="${oldstring//\/>/ Attribute=\"Value\"\/>}"    # replace /> with Attribute="Value"/>

    echo "##################### ${fname}"

    sed "s|${oldstring}|${newstring}|g" "${fname}"
done < proj.dat
```

**NOTES:**

- sed replace applied to all occurences in a file
- if additional datasets cause `sed` to abort with errors it may be necessary to add additional parameter expansions to escape other problematic characters
- added a space on the front of the `Attribute` string since the textual description suggested a space may not exist before the `/>` (eg, `...file.cpp"/>`)
- OP should be able pipe the current `egrep | xargs | egrep | sed`  to this `while` loop (replacing `done < proj.dat` with `done`)
- once OP is satisfied with the results the `-i` flag can be added to the `sed` call to perform an inplace update of `${fname}`

Generates:

```
##################### ./src/base/base.vcxproj
some stuff on this line
             <ClCompile Include="Folder1\Folder1File1.cpp"  Attribute="Value"/>
some more stuff on this line
##################### ./src/mod/mod.vcxproj
some stuff on this line
          <ClCompile Include="Folder2\Folder2File1.cpp"  Attribute="Value"/>
some more stuff on this line
##################### ./src/ext/ext.vcxproj
some stuff on this line
           <ClCompile Include="Folder3\Folder3File1.cpp"  Attribute="Value"/>
some more stuff on this line
```

Comment: This looks very promising and more maintainable, than my attempt at a script. Actually more, than I had hoped for. Will try out tomorrow!